# Visual Studio 2010 How to achieve the solution location with add-in?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, location, add-in, solution

Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location

It is wrong code, because the result is the add-in directory/location.

I would like to open a file on the directory.

Comment: can you please explain in detail

Comment: Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() returns your executable location not the solution path. Why did you want to achieve the project solution path ?

Comment: Because I need to open a file on directory.

Comment: As per standards, your file should be located in the known(static/dynamic) location at the storage disk.  Lets say, either the same location as of your executable or any system specific eg- AppData, Local or UserData locations.

Answer (score 0):

```
 EnvDTE80.Solution2 solution2;
 string solutionFileFullName;
 string solutionFolderFullName; 
 Solution2 = (EnvDTE80.Solution2)_applicationObject.Solution;               
                        solutionFileFullName = solution2.FileName;                  
                        solutionFolderFullName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(solutionFileFullName);
```

Source:

http://www.mztools.com/articles/2013/MZ2013022.aspx